# Getting New Session Id before session expires,checkout/session car is empty even cart has item

Tags: magento-1.7, session, addtocart, singleton

I have a local module, which adds product to cart.To add to cart i have some conditional check before adding to cart,and i am using `getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()` object for getting number of items in cart.

My code, initially checks number of items in cart in that session,by below code.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->hasItems())
{
}
```

adding Product to cart code,

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$product = $this->_initProduct();
$related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
$this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

My Question is , sometimes hasItems() returns false even my cart has products.

**EDIT**

I tried logging `session_id()`, an i found that this session_id changed unexpectedly. That means new session is created , so my cart is empty in this new session.

**My Question?**

I dont create any session in my code, then why new session is created before the session timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `checkout/session` model in wrong way. It should be

```
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
```

So your condition will look like

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->hasItems()) {
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: its typo,i just updated it.and is that right getting cart object as`getModel('checkout/cart')`.

Comment: try to print `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()` and check whether any quotes exist

Comment: Thats what i'm doing.when i check it, it shows empty when i tryto add product  even cart has item, so to understand the session , i log the session id and it logs new session_id .

Comment: did you try `Mage::getModel()` instead of `Mage::getSingleton()` ??

Comment: yes i tried that too.But why you asked me to use `getModel()` any specific reason?

Comment: that is because in both cases, the returning object is different. But if you found out that the session changes due to some reason,then there is nothing to do with your code. You need to find the real reason that kills the session. As per the given details, this is the max that I can help you.